# How come this algorithm in Ruby runs faster than in Parallel'd C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, performance, algorithm, task-parallel-library

The following ruby code runs in ~15s. It barely uses any CPU/Memory (about 25% of one CPU):

```
def collatz(num)
   num.even? ? num/2 : 3*num + 1
end

start_time = Time.now
max_chain_count = 0
max_starter_num = 0
(1..1000000).each do |i|
    count = 0
    current = i
    current = collatz(current) and count += 1 until (current == 1)
    max_chain_count = count and max_starter_num = i if (count > max_chain_count)
end

puts "Max starter num: #{max_starter_num} -> chain of #{max_chain_count} elements. Found in: #{Time.now - start_time}s"
```

And the following TPL C# puts all my 4 cores to 100% usage and is orders of magnitude slower than the ruby version:

```
static void Euler14Test()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int max_chain_count = 0;
    int max_starter_num = 0;
    object locker = new object();
    Parallel.For(1, 1000000, i =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        int current = i;
        while (current != 1)
        {
            current = collatz(current);
            count++;
        }
        if (count > max_chain_count)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                max_chain_count = count;
                max_starter_num = i;
            }
        }
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Max starter i: {0} -> chain of {1} elements. Found in: {2}s", max_starter_num, max_chain_count, sw.Elapsed.ToString());
}

static int collatz(int num)
{
    return num % 2 == 0 ? num / 2 : 3 * num + 1;
}
```

How come ruby runs faster than C#? I've been told that Ruby is slow. Is that not true when it comes to algorithms?

---

Perf AFTER correction:

- Ruby (Non parallel): 14.62s
- C# (Non parallel): 2.22s
- C# (With TPL): 0.64s

Comment: I killed the C# method after a minute or so.

Comment: Out of interest could you run the C# version without using the parallelism, so it matches the ruby logic 1-1. As that would be a more fair comparison, and I would be interested in seeing which is faster then.

Comment: @Grofit I tried that before doing the Parallel.For, it's slow as well (but it's hard to tell exactly how much slower). I'll run it.

Comment: What's the time for non parallel C# version? Just do what you do in Ruby, but in C#. I think that is a valid question in this context.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, the bug is quite subtle, and has nothing to do with threading. The reason that your C# version takes so long is that the intermediate values computed by the `collatz` method eventually start to overflow the `int` type, resulting in negative numbers which may then take ages to converge.

This first happens when `i` is 134,379, for which the 129<sup>th</sup> term (assuming one-based counting) is 2,482,111,348. This exceeds the maximum value of 2,147,483,647 and therefore gets stored as -1,812,855,948.

To get good performance (and correct results) on the C# version, just change:

```
int current = i;
```

…to:

```
long current = i;
```

…and:

```
static int collatz(int num)
```

…to:

```
static long collatz(long num)
```

That will bring down your performance to a respectable 1.5 seconds.

**Edit**: CodesInChaos raises a very valid point about enabling overflow checking when debugging math-oriented applications. Doing so would have allowed the bug to be immediately identified, since the runtime would throw an `OverflowException`.

[image: Overflow checking]

[image: OverflowException]

Comment: BRILLIANT, thanks. I had noticed promptly a negative number, but I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Wow! +100000! (and a few more zeros for the character limit)

Comment: I recommend compiling C# programs with checked arithmetic, at least while debugging. In this case a clear sign was that it quickly worked through the `i`s until it suddenly stopped. This indicated an endless loop, for which an int-overflow is the most likely cause.

Comment: @Linuxios , beware of too many zeros, you might downvote the answer in case of overflow...

Comment: See! C# .NET _is_ faster than Ruby! CONFIRMATION BIAS ***HOOOOOOOOO***

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: No, this confirms my bias that C# is bloated. :).

Comment: @MarceloBiffara: After removing parallelization (to make the test fair), targetting .NET 4 on x64, I get 2.5s. I don't have a Ruby setup, but the OP reported ~15s on their machine.

Comment: @Douglas That is about what I get on my machine as well. I'll add the numbers on the question.

Answer (score 6):

Should be:

```
Parallel.For(1L, 1000000L, i =>
    {
```

Otherwise, you have integer overfill and start checking negative values. The same `collatz` method should operate with long values.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced something like that. And I figured out that's because each of your loop iterations need to start other thread and this takes some time, and in this case it's comparable (I think it's more time) than the operations you acctualy do in the loop body.

There is an alternative for that: You can get how many CPU cores you have and than use a parallelism loop with the same number of iterations you have cores, each loop will evaluate part of the acctual loop you want, it's done by making an inner for loop that depends on the parallel loop.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE**

```
int start = 1, end = 1000000;
Parallel.For(0, N_CORES, n =>
{
    int s = start + (end - start) * n / N_CORES;
    int e = n == N_CORES - 1 ? end : start + (end - start) * (n + 1) / N_CORES;
    for (int i = s; i < e; i++)
    {
        // Your code
    }
});
```

You should try this code, I'm pretty sure this will do the job faster.

**EDIT: ELUCIDATION**

Well, quite a long time since I answered this question, but I faced the problem again and finally understood what's going on.

I've been using AForge implementation of Parallel for loop, and it seems like, it fires a thread for each iteration of the loop, so, that's why if the loop takes relatively a small amount of time to execute, you end up with a inefficient parallelism.

So, as some of you pointed out, System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel methods are based on Tasks, which are kind of a [higher level of abstraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) of a Thread:

"Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been enhanced with algorithms that determine and adjust to the number of threads and that provide load balancing to maximize throughput. This makes tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to enable fine-grained parallelism."

So yeah, if you use the default library's implementation, you won't need to use this kind of "bogus".

Comment: @Baboon: posted an example.

Comment: You can have possible integer overfill here: [start + (end - start) * (n + 1) / N_CORES] and here: [start + (end - start) * n / N_CORES], if N_CORES value is quite big.

Comment: do you mean overflow @ValtasarIII? And I really can't see why it could give me overflow if `N_CORES` is big, not even HOW could `N_CORES` be so big!?

Comment: Well, he's using locks, I didn't see that, with locks this shouldn't give much difference, but with independent parallel (simple, fast) operations this works faster.

Comment: You never specified value for N_CORES. If it is fairly big (say 5000) you will have overfill here: [int s = (end - start) * n/ N_CORES]. You can check your code with N_CORES = 5000 and see that value for s became negative when n=2148.

Comment: @ValtasarIII, N_CORES is the number if cores you have in your computer, and I don't expect it will ever have 5000 cores :) I didn't specified the value because this is not a compilable example. You must get this value from parallel api.

Comment: It is not necessary to go through this kind of trouble with the TPL, it will distribute the work as it sees fit (and you'll notice it fires more thread than cores in most cases)

Comment: Yeah @Baboon I know that, but I'm telling you, that I had experienced that this approach works faster in certain situations where the loop body is really fast to evaluate...

Comment: And, as I'm telling you @Baboon, there is another situation where I found out this can help: Suppose you need to evaluate the sum or something of a big array, to use parallelism for it, you'll have to cut your job in smaller parts because your acumulator can't be in more than one operation at once, otherwise it won't have the right result (without using locks, if you do the parallelism is almost pointless). Than what I mean is that you cut your work N_CORES and into each loop you do part of the work, at the end you just sum (or something else) N_CORES objects and you'll have the result...

Comment: faster than any other possible way I can figure out. By the way, it turned out that this isn't the best answer for this specific question, but I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Well, quite a long time, but I got to understand the downvotes, edited answer again.